# Creating a segue from a button in an external XIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have button on a `UITableViewCell` designed in an external nib. I was wondering how to create segue to a view on the storyboard editor from this button.

I'm a little new to all this, so if you could explain the process I'd be really grateful.

Comment: I don't think you can create a segue from an external xib...segues is only storyboard feature. Correct me if I wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't exactly do that.  Assuming the table view that will hold the custom cell is in a view controller within the storyboard, you can create a segue from that controller to the target controller and give the segue a name.  Then, when the cell's button is tapped, have it tell its controller to call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

Comment: Right, so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Which part are you asking about?

Comment: Well if I make an IBAction for the button, how would I be able to call the performSegue in a different ViewController? Thanks.

Comment: I assume the view controller loads the cell, so it can set itself to listen for a notification that a button on the cell sends.  When the button is tapped, it can post a notification and include any information that its controller needs to pass to the new controller.

Comment: Ok, so this is turning into a pretty complex procedure. Thanks for your answers, I'll get cracking with this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Agreed.  The fact that iOS doesn't let you create a segue in code causes some pain when you try to combine a storyboard and non-storyboard elements.

Comment: Well that's the problem. I'm ok with the notification bit, but actually setting up the segue is causing me some problems. How do I even set it up without setting it to an IBAction on the TableView?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Thanks for all the help. I personally think It'd be awesome if you could design TableViewCells and whatnot in the storyboard, as if it were an extra nib.